# Вывод sysname из os.uname

Tags: python

При написании os.uname выводится sysname, nodename, release и т.д. Нужно вывести только sysname. Пытатся ли это сделать через uname или использовать другой метод?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этого метода достаточно

```
>>> os.uname().sysname
'Linux'
```